# Javascript form validation not executing and input text box height cursor positioning not setting to top.

Tags: javascript, html, css, forms

I created a simple contact form, I am trying to use javascript for validation to make sure all fields get filled out, I have the following html code.

```
        <form method="post" action="send.php" onSubmit="checkEmail()" >
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td><h1>Name: </h1></td>
                <td><input type="text" max="30" name="name" placeholder="What should I call you?"/></td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td><h1>EMAIL: </h1></td>
                <td><input type="email" max="50" name="email" placeholder="email"/> </td>
            </tr> 

            <tr>
                <td valign="top"><h1>Message</h1></td>
                <td><input id="message" type="textbox" name="message" max="1000" align="texttop" placeholder="Whats up?" /></td>
            </tr>

            <tr><td></td><td><input type="submit" name="send" value="SEND" /></td></tr>
        </table>
        </form>
```

And here is my javascript

```
function checkEmail(){
if(form.email.value==" "){

    alert("Please enter a email");
}
```

}

But instead of alerting users if they have not filled out the form the form simply executes the php file I typed for the action attribute.

Another issue I am having is I gave the message input field a width of 300px and the text box did get bigger but the cursor inside the text box still is in the middle of the box and when I type the input just keeps going and going without dropping to another line within the box.

Comment: As for the second part- are you looking for `textarea`?

Comment: Yes, here is what I have in the text area, http://jsfiddle.net/V2wGn/ its set to 300px for height, I set valign to top but the cursor still shows in the middle of the box  when you try to type, also the text goes on and on without breaking to the next line when users type.

Comment: I ended up using <textarea> instead of <input type="text">

Answer (score 0):

```
function checkEmail(){

if(document.forms[0].email.value==""){

    alert("Please enter a email");
    return false;
}else{
    return true;
}
}
```

and

```
<form method="post" action="send.php" onsubmit="return checkEmail()" >
```

http://jsfiddle.net/5Dy89/1/

Comment: I tried that also but not luck. As soon as I hit the submit button the action executes instead of my onSubmit attribute.

Comment: Awesome this worked thank you. When you write forms[0] what is the 0 for? is forms data returned as an array?

Comment: @user2684521 `document.forms` is basically an array of every form in your document... You can also access the forms by their name attributes so that order doesn't matter. Then you'd either use `document.forms.formName` or `document.forms["formName"]` to get `<form name="formName">`.

Comment: I see, thank you for taking the time to explain that to me. I very much appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

This may help. There are many ways to go about this. But this is one way and I've used it dozens of times

First identify your form:

```
<form action="send.php" id="myForm" name="myForm" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

form code here

and then do this to your send button

```
<div> <a onclick="document.getElementById('myForm').submit()"><span>Send</span></a> </div>
```

That oughtta get it to post the info to your server and get it back after processed when submit is clicked

Answer (score 0):

There is no "form" variable defined. Either use document.forms[0].email.value, or the preferred way would be to give each of your inputs an id:

Input Element:

```
<input type="email" max="50" id="email" name="email" placeholder="email"/>
```

JavaScript:

```
function checkEmail() {
    if(document.getElementById("email").value === "") {
        alert("Please enter an email").
        //return false to prevent submit when using onsubmit directly on form
        return false;
    }
}
```

Make sure to use return in your form tag too:

```
<form method="post" action="send.php" onsubmit="return checkEmail();">
```

Answer (score 0):

You might as well use the `this` keyword to keep track of your form at all times. For JavaScript, it's just a matter of reassigning what `this` is to your function.

```
<form onsubmit="return checkEmail.call(this);"><!-- More goes here --></form>
```

Then your JavaScript function can just access `this`:

```
function checkEmail() {
  var valid = !!this.email.value.match(/\S/); // Checks for anything but spaces
  if(!valid)
    alert('Please enter an email.');
  return valid; // If true is returned for onsubmit, it sends off the form
}
```